# Layout for big form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have form in my application that contains over 10 different fields (**textboxes**, **dropdoxns** ets.). And there is a lot of copy-pasted fragment like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
</div>
```

Only `EditorFor` is a part that changes. Label and wrapping divs are the same.
How can I move repeated part of HTML? I tried partial and editors but have no idea of how to specify generic editor inside 2nd div cause it can be also dropdown, checkbox etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a drop down in the view and add a dropdown like MyFirstNameList to thew view model in your controller by doing something list this...

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class YourController
{    
        private yourdatacontext db = new yourdatacontext ();

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewModels.YourViewModel model = new ViewModels.YourViewModel ();

            model.MyFirstNameList = new SelectList(db.FirstNames, "Id", "Name");

            return View(model);
         }
}
```

and then you can just do this on the view...

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => m.FirstName, Model.MyFirstNameList, "--- Select a Name ----")
```